# What this macro return?

Tags: c, macros

I've seen using the return value of this macro, but from the definition I can't understnad which is the value that the execution returns.

```
   // packet parsing state machine helpers
    #define cursor_advance(_cursor, _len) \
      ({ void *_tmp = _cursor; _cursor += _len; _tmp; })
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Macros don't return anything. Instead invocation of the macros are replaced inline with the body of the macro (with the macro arguments substituted).

So if you have the code

```
some_variable = cursor_advance(my_cursor, some_length);
```

then the preprocessor replaces that with

```
some_variable = ({ void *_tmp = my_cursor; my_cursor += some_length; _tmp; });
```

This in turn is an extension to the C language by the GCC C compiler called [*statement expression*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). It evaluates the statements between the `({` and `})`, and the result is the last expression. In the case of the example above the result is `_tmp`.

---

The whole expression

```
some_variable = ({ void *_tmp = my_cursor; my_cursor += some_length; _tmp; });
```

is equivalent to the statements

```
{
    void * _tmp = my_cursor;
    my_cursor += some_length;
    some_variable = _tmp;
}
```

Comment: "and the result is the last expression" So it's like the comma operator?

Comment: @Ayxan Similar, but allow arbitrary statements before the resulting expression.

Comment: u8 *cursor = 0;
struct ethernet_t *ethernet = cursor_advance(cursor, sizeof(*ethernet));
so here  cursor value will be assigned to ethernet while cursor will be increased by the size of a pointer to ethernet right?

Answer (score 0):

The macro returns the pointer _tmp

This is a gcc feature : http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs